# Ajustar tamaño de lista desplegable de un SELECT

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, script, html-select

Tengo una carga de datos que muestro con un SELECT que se ve inicialmente de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el usuario quiere escoger el Sub-Tema Nivel 2 y abre el select se ve de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es ajustar el texto para que lo muestre mas pequeño, código es el siguiente:

```html
$temas_N2 = "SELECT * FROM temas_n2";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $temas_N2);

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sub-Tema Nivel 2<span class="required">*</span></label>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_tema_N2" id="id_tema_N2" data-live-search="true">
      <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona Sub-Tema Nivel 2 --</option>
      <?php foreach ($result as $p): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $p['descripcion']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y el selectpicker lo tengo de esta forma

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    success: function(data) {
      $("#selectpicker").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
    }
  });
  $(function() {
    $('#mod_id_tema_N2_selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    success: function(data) {
      $("#mod_id_tema_N2_selectpicker").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar esto para resolverlo:

```
var maxLength = 15;
$('#example > option').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        return text.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';  
    }
});
```

Esto simplemente revisa las opciones y su largo. Si el largo es mayor al largo máximo, será cortado al largo máximo, y se le agregarán puntos suspensivos.

### [Acá hay un ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/wCUA6/1/)

Comment: Editaste el codigo o solo lo copiaste? hay cosas que cambiar, el ejemplo demuestra que si funciona.

Comment: Lo aplique al que hace el llamado del formulario principal y no al modal y funciono, gracias

Comment: Eso está mejor. Siempre debes verificar que estás ingresando bien el código ;) el ejemplo demuestra que si funciona. Recuerda marcarlo como respuesta, te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca un style a tu select = style="width:100% !important;"

```
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_tema_N2" id="id_tema_N2" data-live-search="true" style="width:100% !important;">
      <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona Sub-Tema Nivel 2 --</option>
      <?php foreach ($result as $p): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $p['descripcion']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: esto no me funcionó